# Recursion to loop

Tags: c, recursion, iteration

I've been given an assignment of writing both recurring and iterating programs of function, defined as:

> **T(n,0)=n, n>=0** 
>   **T(0,m)=m, m>=0** 
>   **T(n,m)=T(n-1,m)+2*T(n, m-1)**

I am allowed to use only basic operations (so +, -, *, /, %) and not allowed to use most of "outside" functions from any libraries.
Writing recursion for that wasn't that much of a problem (code is in C):

```
int fTrec(int n, int m)
{  
    if(n==0)
        return m;
    else if(m==0)
        return n;
    else
        return(fTrec(n-1, m)+2*fTrec(n, m-1));
}
```

However, making it into iteration turned out to be impossible for me. I've been trying to get it done for quite a while now, I've read quite a lot about it on internet - with very little success. 
Every tip and all the help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Small edit: Forgot to add, I am limited to most basic tools and possibilites of C language. By this I mean using only one dimensional arrays, no pointers etc.

Comment: You might now have a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function :)

Comment: Isn't the declaration of your problem wrong? Shouldn't the second line be **T(0,m)=m, m>=0** instead?

Comment: @Rightleg Yeah, my bad. Edited it, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Still wrong, should be **T(0,m)** instead of **T(m,0)** :)

Comment: Heh, I don't seem to be too bright today. Edited once more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compute the function iteratively by building up a table of results. This is very much in the spirit of making a dynamic programming solution that computes a recursive formula.

Here's some example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fTiter(int n, int m) {  
    int T[n+1][m+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        T[i][0] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= m; i++) {
        T[0][i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
            T[i][j] = T[i-1][j] + 2 * T[i][j-1];
        }
    }
    return T[n][m];
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            printf("% 8d ", fTiter(j, i));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It's possible to optimise the code to use a 1D array only. This works using essentially the same method as the 2D version, but reuses elements of the array in a careful and subtle way. It uses simpler C features than the 2D version but it's definitely not simpler code, and I personally find it a lot harder to understand.

```
int fTiter(int n, int m) {  
    int T[n+1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        T[i] = i;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= m; i++) {
        T[0] = i;
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            T[j] = T[j-1] + 2 * T[j];
        }
    }
    return T[n];
}
```

Comment: Not that this solution requires C99 and allocates `T` on the stack, which may be too large for such an allocation, depending on `n` and `m` of course.

Comment: Yes it's C99 and potentially limited by stack. But n and m can't get too large anyway because the function grows exponentially and entries quickly overflow even a 64 bit int.

Comment: The code as written also assumes int has at least 24 bits ;)

Comment: That's a neat way to solve it and someone could use those ideas to theirs code. However, I forgot to add I'm supposed to be as basic as possible - no two-dimensional arrays, pointers etc. I should've been way more precisive when asking my question.

Comment: You can use a 1D array to represent the table: `int T[(n+1) * (m+1)]` with `T[i][j]` becoming `T[i * (m+1) + j]`. The code is otherwise essentially the same (only messier) and I'll leave it to you to finish your homework ;)

Comment: @TheGroch: When there is a single recursive call in your recurrence function it is often possible to turn the recursive algorithm into a pretty loop. But when there are multiple recursive calls it gets trickier. The general approach would be to use stacks to simulate the recursion by hand, which would end up very hard to read. For the kind of relation you see in the problem Paul's table-driven solution is the most natural way to solve it.

Comment: I added a sneaky version of the code that uses a 1D array. Good luck understanding it :)

Comment: Why does nobody write preincrements today?

Comment: Anyway, your 1D solution is amazing.

Comment: Awesome, both answers work great. I've managed to get similar 1D solution by myself based on 2D code, only using two arrays. Not too bad for a noob like me ;)